# How to manage memory in swift?

Tags: ios, iphone, memory-management, swift2

I've imported `iPod` Library to `mediaQuery` variable.

```
var mediaQuery = MPMediaQuery!
```

after making the query, that loads the library.

```
override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
super.didReceiveMemoryWaring()
mediaQuery = nil }
```

`mediaQuery` to nil makes it to use less memory ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Swift has its own garbage collector. Setting a variable to nil will free the memory. This code doesn't work in Swift 2 because you specify the object must exist by using a `!` after the type. The code should be as follows:

```
var mediaquery: MPMediaQuery?

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
  super.didReceiveMemoryWaring()
  mediaquery = nil
}
```

Comment: But it didn't give me any Error or warning.

I used MPMediaQuery! and i assigned it to nil, it didn't give me any Error.

Comment: Automatic Reference counting or ARC, is a form of garbage collection in which objects are deallocated once there are no more references to them. Each object, under ARC, contains a reference counter, stored as an extra field in memory, which is incremented every time you set a variable to that object , and is decremented every time you set a reference to the object to nil/null, or a reference goes out of scope, once the reference counter goes down to zero, the object takes care of deleting itself, calling the destructor and freeing the allocated memory.

Comment: Letus, ARC is NOT a form of garbage collector. Kristina asks if setting mediaQuery to nil makes it to use less memory. The answer is no. Setting implicitly unwrapped optional to nil will not dealocate any memory and will not give her any error. If she will use the reference to mediaQuery for something after that, the program simply crash ...